# jQuery String Replace in breadcrumb

Tags: jquery, replace

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.breadcrumbs').text(function (i, old) {
return old
.replace('Your-Space', 'Your Space') });
});
```

I have this "Your-Space" text in the breadcrumbs at the top and the above snippet does replace my text with "Your Space", without "-".

But "Your Space" is also a link to that particular category, and the function above removes the link, why is that happening?

**Update:** 
HTML: (if breadcrumb is one level deep)

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="http://www.xxx.com" title="Go to Home.">Home</a> &gt; Your-Tennis-Space</div>
```

HTML: (if in a category)

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="http://www.xxx.com" title="Go to Home.">Home</a> &gt; 
<a href="http://www.xxx.com/your-space/" title="Go to Your-Space.">Your-Space</a>
```

> Browse Categories

**Update2:**

This is getting confused for me and probably for you two guys as well. To clear it, this snippet works, it does the job:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.breadcrumbs').html(function (i, old) {
return old.replace('Your-Space', 'Your Space') });
});
```

But I have the breadcrumbs and when the path is Home > Your Space, "Your Space" is not a link. When I click on a category, I will get the following path where Your Space becomes a link = Home > Your Space > Some random category.

Now, the whole thing work IF I select both classes separately:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.breadcrumbs').html(function (i, old) {
return old.replace('Your-Space', 'Your Space') });
});
```

AND

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.breadcrumbs a').html(function (i, old) {
return old.replace('Your-Space', 'Your Space') });
});
```

**(with and without a)**

IF I select them like that (jQuery('.breadcrumbs, .breadcrumbs a')), it doesn't work as in, just the .breadcrumbs is changed, not when is link, so it doesn't selects .breadcrumbs .

I hope is clear enough, I had to this for me at least as I am very confused now lol.

Comment: can you include your HTML - is breadcrumb a class of an anchor ?

Comment: I've done it in the past and I will be doing it now aswell. I do not feel which one is the appropriate answer as both of you are kinda right but this doesn't solve my problem at all and I kinda got more confused than before.

Comment: I didnt mean specifically for this question - for all of your questions ....

Comment: You are right! I am now reading all my previous questions and will accept the right answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT :** 
Here is an example using the parent div as the selector : http://jsfiddle.net/Ax6ps/1/

```
$('#mybut').click(function() {
    $('.parent-breadcrumb a').text(function(i, old) {
        return old.replace('Click', 'Your Space');
    });
});
```

**OLD ->**
Works fine in this example : http://jsfiddle.net/Ax6ps/

```
<a href="index.html" class="breadcrumb">Click</a><br/>
<a href="index.html" class="breadcrumb">Click</a><br/>
<a href="index.html" class="breadcrumb">Click</a><br/>
<a href="index.html" class="breadcrumb">Click</a><br/>
<a href="index.html" class="breadcrumb">Click</a><br/>
<input type="button" value="Do Something" id="mybut"/>


$('#mybut').click(function() {
    $('.breadcrumb').text(function(i, old) {
        return old.replace('Click', 'Your Space');
    });
});
```

Comment: It works for me if I change text with html ($('.breadcrumb').XXX) and if I duplicate the snippet, each with it's own targeted css path (.breadcrumbs a and .breadcrumbs). But if I select them like that, .breadcrumbs a, .breadcrumbs -> doesn't work.

Comment: @CristianDemetriad understood .... try using this plugin -> http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/ will just replace the text (anywhere) and leave the HTML untouched.

Comment: I wasn't able to select the class and didn't work for me, I left it like I said but I will have to change it as this is not a good solution at all. I will get back to this tomorrow.

Comment: @CristianDemetriad use the plugin i linked - its exactly what you want - it replaces text and doesnt care if you have HTML tags or not - it leaves them alone.

Comment: I was talking about the plugin. I will try again today, thank you for your continous help on this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.breadcrumbs').html(function (i, old) {
  return old.replace('Your-Space', 'Your Space') });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the link anymore but won't change the text. It does change the text though when the breadcrumb is just one level deep: Home -> Your Space but when you go into a category like Home -> Your Space -> Name of category, it doesn't change it. However, I found that I should apply this snippet to "breadcrumbs a" and it does the trick; thank you very much for your help anyway :).

Comment: Hang on, I am wrong. Adding "breadcrumbs a" doesn't change the string if is "Home -> Your Space ->"! But it does if the breadcrumb is "Home -> Your Space -> Name of category". With your suggested solution, is the other way round. If I try with both versions, it's the same probably I initially had.

Comment: .text function doesn't allow any html tags. theyre stripped in output. I can't help more without your html markup

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.breadcrumbs a').text(function (i, old) {
return old.replace('Your-Space', 'Your Space') });
});
```